# Making a wall very slightly thicker with gypsum board?

Tags: walls, sound-proofing

In the flat I'm remodeling, there is a very thin wall, like 6cm thick or so separating two large rooms. It has literally no sound isolation, and is overall very flimsy - it does not help that it is not made of brick, but some porous, dark grey-ish material. The wall is reasonably straight though.

Would it be possible to cement gypsum board onto both sides of this wall using very thin layer of gypsum board cement, like 1-2 mm, spread on whole surface? I'd definitely use screws too to fix it to the existing walls.

I don't want to build a full fledged gypsum board structure as there is a door on the wall, and due to its ornaments it would look really ugly - but a single layer of gypsum board would actually look better.

I think this would result in a significantly more stable wall - the original material even has a trouble holding screws...

Comment: A few pics please.  That would help us determine what a solution may be.

Comment: Sounds easier to take it out and build a real wall there. You could even build it with alternating-iffser studs for better sound isolation, and then fill it with sand if you want a studio-quality sound barrier ...

Comment: Just adding extra drywall/gypsum board will probably not dampen sound that much.  Sound travels though hard stuff, soft stuff tends to adsorbed sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can glue drywall ("gypsum board") to surfaces, assuming the surface will actually hold when glued to (if it's merely porous and has poor screw holding, that might be OK, but if the stuff is so weak the glue will pull off a layer of it and the drywall falls down, not OK.) The glue used for adhering the sheets to a wall is NOT the same as the joint compound used to finish the joints on the face of the wall.

It probably won't help much with sound transmission.

That wall is abnormally thin and perhaps structurally dubious (even as a non-bearing partition wall.)